TwinCAT: Axis Drive not enabled/ready
The problem
I'm new to TwinCAT, and following a tutorial to get started with Motion Control. Trying to jog my servo, I'm haven't been able to get past the error The axis respectively the drive is not enabled/ready for positioning (error-code: 0x4225) !
What I have tried
I have the axis controls enabled on the Online tab: screenshot. (Otherwise the error would be Axis/Group or coupled slave axis has none enabled controller and, therefore, does not take an instruction (error-code: 0x4260) !, but I'm okay there)
The I/O is linked on the Axis/Settings page, the motor is selected on the Motor-drive-card/Drive Manager page.
I also swapped out the servo for a new one, but nothing changed. 
I can toggle I/O lights, so I have a connection, but the encoder doesn't update position information that should be coming from the servo. Scanning my connections reveals that my project organization is identical to what it finds on the machine.
Here's what the Online screen looks like, and clearing the error and enabling again hasn't seemed to change anything. screenshot, And here are my axis settings: screenshot
Sorry for the newbie question, I'm probably just missing a config setting or something. Let me know if there's any other information I can include to be more helpful, and thank you!

Been a while since I worked with NC, but the fact that the position is not updated means that something is wrong with the configuration of your axis - if you manually spin the rotor, does the position update? Perhaps send the settings tab of the axis as well and what your actual setup looks like (integrated encoder, separate encoder, etc...)

@ziga Nope, the position doesn't update at any point, with either of the servos I've tested. I've now put my Axis settings there on the post, do they give you any clues?

I think that it might be a hardware / wiring issue. Can you provide a list of hardware used (PLC, all ethercat terminals up to  EL7211, cable, servomotor) as well as a picture of EL7211 wiring?

A picture of EL7211 LEDs would also help, since it has decent diagnostics.

Thank you guys for taking a look at it! I've now tried wiring up two different servos on both drives, and neither work. Trying to scan the drive with Drive Manger 2 results in a simple No motor is found. Trying the same thing with a different laptop on TwinCAT also didn't help. Here is my wiring: https://i.sstatic.net/yrNpnS90.jpg  https://i.sstatic.net/f514gj46.jpg
Hardware used: EK1100, EL7211, AM8112-0F20-000, MU00004

Am I assuming correctly, that you are using your laptop as PLC ethercat master instead of Beckhoff IPC? If so, have you installed the drivers for your network card? You can do it by running C:/TwinCAT/3.1/System/TcRteInstall.exe

Thank you all for the help! I've found a solution and explained it below.

Solved!
As shown in the images I'd attached, I was using EL7211 cards, the double width ones with a blank right side. Those must be incompatible with TwinCAT 4024.56 or something, because swapping them out with a EL7211 that has a 9014 on the right has it working! Wiring Setup
It seems that was the issue. If anyone has insights as to why that was a problem I'd love to understand it better, but now the motor and encoder at least work.
